# Celery beat scheduling option to immediately launch task upon celery launch

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I can schedule an hourly task in my Django app using celery beat in `settings.py` like so:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
'tasks.my_task':{
'task':'tasks.my_task',
'schedule':timedelta(seconds=60*60),
'args':(),
},
}
```

But is there a way to schedule a task such that it *immediately* queues up and is calculated, thereafter following the configured schedule from there on? E.g., something like executing a selected task instantly at celery launch. What's the configuration for that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `tasks.py`:

```
obj = locals()['task_function_name']
obj.run()
```

This ensures the specified task is run when celery is run. Thereafter, it executes according to schedule.